# Mock database and response from endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

I want to create a JUnit test for this code:

```java
private Service listsService;
    
    
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET}, path = {"id/{id}"})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> find(@PathVariable String id) {
    
        LookupResponse lookupResponse = listsService.findById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(lookupResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
       .................
    
@Override
public LookupResponse findById(String id) {
    
    Optional<Lists> list = ListsRepository.findById(id);
    
    if(list.isPresent())
    {
        Lists lists = binList.get();
        LookupResponse response = LookupResponse.builder()
               .countryCode(lists.getCountry())
                        .category(lists.getType())
                        .build())
               .build();
    
        return response;
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

I tried this:

```
public class ControllerTest {

@MockBean
private ListsService listsService;

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Test
void justAnExample() {

    LookupResponse lookupResponse = LookupResponse.builder()
            .type("123456")
            .build();

    
   Mockito.when(listsService.findById(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(lookupResponse);


}
```

}

When I run the code JUnit code is making requests to database. How I can mock the connection?

Comment: As you using `MockMvc` does it initialize the full application with DB?

Comment: is the test class annotated somehow? you are missing an annotation like @SpringBootTest or @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class); otherwise a plain old test class will ignore the mock/autowired annotations

Comment: yes, that was missing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use @MockBean, you will need to annotate the test class with or `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` or `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` if using JUnit 4. You can also use `@SpringJUnitConfig`, which combines `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` with `@ContextConfiguration` See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html

The rest can stay the same:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class ControllerTest {

@MockBean
private ListsService listsService;

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Test
void justAnExample() {

    LookupResponse lookupResponse = LookupResponse.builder()
            .type("123456")
            .build();

    
   Mockito.when(listsService.findById(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(lookupResponse);


}
```

Comment: I get `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Comment: Do you have the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency in your maven/gradle config?

Comment: yes: `    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'`

Answer (score 0):

1. Here is example for WebClient mocking in tests:
   https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mocking-webclient
2. And for RestTemplate mocking in tests:
   https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mock-rest-template

To mock database it depends what would you like to achieve.

1. You can mock db repository with

   Mockito.when(mock.findById(id)).thenReturn(mockedresponse)
2. In addition there is ability to override properties in
   `src/main/resources/application.properties` with `src/test/resources/application.properties` and make spring test context to be connected to H2 database
   please read example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-separate-data-source

Answer (score 0):

You're mocking the `ListsService` using `@MockBean`, but are not injecting it into the controller using `@Autowired` or `@InjectMocks`. As a result, the controller is still using the real `ListsService` instead of the mocked one, and therefore making real database calls.

To fix this issue try to inject the mocked ListsService into the controller using either @Autowired or @InjectMocks annotations.

It would look similar to this code

```
@Mock 
ListsRepository listsRepository;

@InjectMocks
ListsService listsService = new ListsServiceImpl();

@Test
void justAnExample() {
    LookupResponse lookupResponse = LookupResponse.builder()
            .type("123456")
            .build();
    when(listsRepository.findById(anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.of(new Lists()));
    when(listsService.findById(anyString())).thenReturn(lookupResponse);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/id/1"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.type", equalTo("123456")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To mock the connection to the database, you can use the `@MockBean` annotation provided by Spring Boot, which allows you to mock a bean in the application context. In your case, you can mock the `ListsRepository` bean, which is responsible for accessing the database.

Here is an example of how to do it:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = Controller.class)
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ListsService listsService;

    @MockBean
    private ListsRepository listsRepository;

    @Test
    public void testFind() throws Exception {
        // create a LookupResponse object to be returned by the mock service
        LookupResponse lookupResponse = LookupResponse.builder()
                .countryCode("US")
                .category("foo")
                .build();

        // configure the mock service to return the LookupResponse object
        when(listsService.findById("1")).thenReturn(lookupResponse);

        // configure the mock repository to return a Lists object when findById is called with "1"
        Lists lists = new Lists();
        lists.setCountry("US");
        lists.setType("foo");
        when(listsRepository.findById("1")).thenReturn(Optional.of(lists));

        // perform the HTTP GET request
        mockMvc.perform(get("/id/1"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().json("{countryCode: 'US', category: 'foo'}"));
    }
}
// Fixed by FixThisCode.com
```

In this example, we are using the `@WebMvcTest` annotation to test the Controller class, which means that only the web layer of the application will be tested, and not the whole context. We are also using the `@MockBean` annotation to mock the `ListsService` and `ListsRepository` beans.

Inside the `testFind()` method, we first create a `LookupResponse` object to be returned by the mock service. We then configure the mock service to return this object when its `findById()` method is called with the argument "1".

We also configure the mock repository to return a Lists object when its `findById()` method is called with the argument "1". This object will be used by the service to create the `LookupResponse` object.

Finally, we use the `MockMvc` object to perform an HTTP GET request to the /id/1 endpoint, and we verify that the response has a status code of 200 and a JSON body that matches the expected `LookupResponse` object.

Comment: I get `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.ListsService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

Comment: See what they say about it on [fixthiscode.com](https://fixthiscode.com)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're trying to test whether your filters are working, there's not much reason to use `MockBean` or `WebMvcTest`.  I would consider that more of an integration or smoke test, and it is beneficial when you're making dependency changes, upgrading libraries, etc.

For unit tests, I would write the test to only test my logic, nothing else.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ControllerTest {

    @Mock
    // mock your service
    private ListsService listsService;

    @InjectMocks
    // inject your mock into your controller
    private MyController myController;

    @Test
    void justAnExample() {
        String lookupValue = "SomeValue";

        LookupResponse lookupResponse = LookupResponse.builder()
                .type("123456")
                .build();

        // I like to be explicit with my matchers so I can ensure the correct
        // value is being passed down to the service
        when(listsService.findById(lookupValue)).thenReturn(lookupResponse);

        ResponseEntity<Object> response = myController.find(lookupValue);
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), is(equalTo(200)));

        // add additional assertions ...
    }
}
```